# how to send an object by servlets

Tags: session, servlets

Yes, i know that some similar questions have asked on this issue.
Anyway, any solution that i saw doesn't solve my problem:

I have servlet 1, there i have an object "area" from type "Area".
This object has some special methods that i created.
I want to send this object to another servlet (servlet 2), such that all the special data of area will be saved.

What i did is:

In servlet 1:

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  session.setAttribute("theArea", area);
```

In servlet 2:

```
   Area aa = (Area) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("theArea");
```

when i am typing after this

```
aa.
```

the general methods of java appears, but not my methods...

I also tried in servlet 1:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("theArea", area);
```

and didn't work.

I will be very happy to help...
Thank's

Comment: what method are you not getting?

Comment: All methods of "Area"-the special object that i created. I see just the java methods, like "clone", "contains", "equal", etc'.

Answer (score 0):

should be a casting problem. Try this

```
Area aa = (Area) (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("theArea"));
```

Comment: i don't know why but when i typed Model.Area (the package) it's solved. Thanks anyway...

Comment: that is because you did not `import` the package previously. Now you are directly accessing the class.